# Enhance image quality after resizing

Tags: iphone, ios, image, resize

Can anyone suggest methods to enhance the quality of an image, being resized to a larger size?
On resizing, the resultant image pixelates. I need this pixelation to reduce to maximum extent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for compressing or increasing size of an image.

```
CGFloat compression = 222.0f;
CGFloat maxCompression = 202.1f;
int maxFileSize = 160*165; //fill your size need

NSData *imageDat = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, compression);

while ([imageDat length] > maxFileSize && compression > maxCompression)
{
compression -= 0.1222;
imageDat = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(decodedimage.image, compression);
}
NSLog(@"image compressed success");

[image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageDat]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for compressing or increasing size of an image.

```
image1 = [self imageWithImage:image1 convertToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)]; 

// For convert the image to fix size

- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image convertToSize:(CGSize)size 
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,460)];
UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return destImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an Article called : [Resize a UIImage the right way](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) , you should Read and Understand each and every aspects given there. I think it will give Answers of Every Questions arises in your mind. I think it's a beautiful Article with proper Graphical Representation (means Less Boring at Reading).